# EQCSS - Responsive table doesn't revert to original style

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I have been trying to make a responsive table that collapses if the cell width is less than 200px, the problem is, once I collapse the table the width of the cell becomes the width of the row. I know I will need to check to see if the row width is greater than the sum of the number of columns * min-width (200px). But I have no idea how to actually achieve it, whatever I try just breaks it completely.

https://codepen.io/scottkane/pen/ExZvbvq

See codepen, make the window smaller to see the element query working, then try making the window bigger again and see that it doesn't revert the styling.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Table</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/eqcss/1.9.2/EQCSS.min.js" integrity="sha512-yfw7F0e6Vqdxeg6nDlK4l4+pyBvwozVA61StkFRHcwW2dTAIRa4rfmvi4xXmcRmcnq4NI3jbOY4B8cc25n5SkA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/eqcss/1.9.2/EQCSS-polyfills.min.js" integrity="sha512-Io6cpd8PlB4UY1JYCy1DzrfG+56EWKTXnwi+w9LdfrNiXaAkSI0EQTqRUO6YjMVqWQv6vF/zc4h0uumlPc1XPg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
                line-height: 1.25;
            }            

            .table {
                color: #262626;
            }

            .table-head {
                font-size: 0.85em;
                font-weight: bold;
                letter-spacing: 0.1em;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #838383;
            }

            .table-row {
                height: auto;
                display: flex;
                gap: 10px;
                padding: 0.75em;
                border-top: 1px solid #838383;
            }
            
            .table-row > div {
                text-align: center;
                flex-basis: 100%;
            }

            @element .table-row > div and (max-width: 200px) {
                .table-head {
                    border: none;
                    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
                    height: 1px;
                    margin: -1px;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    padding: 0px;
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 1px;
                }
                
                .table-row {
                    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
                    display: flex;
                    flex-wrap: wrap;
                    margin-bottom: 0.625em;
                }
                
                .table-row > div {
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
                    display: block;
                    padding: 0.625em;
                    font-size: 0.8em;
                    text-align: right !important;
                    flex-basis: -1px;
                    flex-grow: 1;
                }
                
                .table-row > div::before {
                    content: attr(label);
                    float: left;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                }
                
                .table-row > div:first-child {
                    padding-top: 0px;
                }
                
                .table-row > div:last-child {
                    border-bottom: 0px;
                    padding-bottom: 0px;
                }
            }
        </style>
        <div class="table">
            <div class="table-row table-head">
                <div>Account</div>
                <div>Due Date</div>
                <div>Amount</div>
                <div>Period</div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-row">
                <div label="Account">Visa - 3412</div>
                <div label="Due Date">04/01/2016</div>
                <div label="Amount">$1,190</div>
                <div label="Period">03/01/2016 - 03/31/2016</div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-row">
                <div label="Account">Visa - 6076</div>
                <div label="Due Date">03/01/2016</div>
                <div label="Amount">$2,443</div>
                <div label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-row">
                <div label="Account">Corporate AMEX</div>
                <div label="Due Date">03/01/2016</div>
                <div label="Amount">$1,181</div>
                <div label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-row">
                <div label="Acount">Visa - 3412</div>
                <div label="Due Date">02/01/2016</div>
                <div label="Amount">$842</div>
                <div label="Period">01/01/2016 - 01/31/2016</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with EQCSS library.

I don't know the library, so I'm unable to figure out whether you haven't implemented it properly or it's simply badly written. I suspect the latter, but I don't have enough information.

Here's what's happening in DOM, when your page loads: the JS of the library creates a bunch of empty `<style>` tags when it loads, with `id`s ranging from `data-eqcss-0-0` to `data-eqcss-0-19` (possibly related to the number of library elements found in the page).

It also places a listener on `window.resize`. Once the viewport goes below a particular width (looks like the breakpoint is `874px`), some CSS gets injected into the tags with ids ending in `-0` up to `-3`. From that point on, the content of those 4 `<style>` tags gets rewritten on each `resize` event, always with the same content, making the table render in mobile mode, even when you go above the breakpoint. I suspect the script is supposed to empty the style tags when above the breakpoint, but it fails (looks like a lib bug).

The entire concept of dynamically changing the contents of `<style>` tags based on viewport width states firmly the authors of the library have insufficient knowledge of (or no appreciation for) the power and usefulness of CSS `@media` queries. Which is not a good sign, coming from authors of a UI library.

---

Moving forward, here's a possible fix:

I first tried to empty the culprit `<style>` tags but, as mentioned above, their content gets re-added on next `resize` event.

So I tested deleting them. Sure enough, this time it worked: the table renders correctly once they're gone.
The best part about it is the lib recovers gracefully. Once the page goes below the breakpoint again, the lib re-adds the missing `<style>` tags, with the correct ids, and repopulates them with the necessary code for displaying the table in mobile mode. When above the breakpoint, our script kicks in and removes them again (based on id).

In fewer words, the hack works. Keep in mind I can only guarantee it works for this particular example (with more/less lib elements in the page the style tags generated might differ and the script might need adjustments) .

See it working here: https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/zYNLKWE

Please note the above solution is extremely aggressive and definitely not the sort of hack a page should resort to in order to use a UI library.

My advice would be not to use this hack, but try to contact the lib authors about the bug and ask them to look at it.
It might be something they already fixed in a later version, you could be missing some required part of the library, or it could be a side-effect of something we're both missing and they might spot with ease, since it's their code.